# Reinitialize bootstrap carousel after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I'm setting up the `bootstrap carousel` after the `Ajax call` to the DOM. So, I'm appending elements and classes `after the page load` as below.

```
async function ajaxCall() {
    let data = await fetch('ApiLink');
    let jsonData = await data.json();

    let carousel = document.createElement('section');
    let inner = document.createElement('div');
    carousel.id = 'slider';
    carousel.className = 'carousel carousel-dark slide';
    carousel.setAttribute('data-bs-ride', 'carousel');
    inner.className = 'carousel-inner';

    jsonData.data.forEach(data => {
        let item = document.createElement('div');
        let avatar = document.createElement('img');
        item.className = 'carousel-item';
        avatar.src = data.avatar;
        item.appendChild(avatar);
        inner.appendChild(item);
    });

    inner.querySelector('.carousel-item').classList.add('active');
    carousel.appendChild(inner);
    document.body.appendChild(carousel);
}
```

However, the carousel doesn't work.

I guess, I need to reinitialize the carousel after creating and appending the HTML elements. So, my question is:

How can I reinitialize the bootstrap carousel after the Ajax call **without using jQuery**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#methods), you can make a carousel instance with the carousel constructor after creating your slider element as below:

```
let carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(slider, {});
```

Further, take a look at the carousel methods. So, you can find the `getOrCreateInstance` which returns a carousel instance associated with a DOM element, or create a new one in case it wasn't initialized as below:

```
bootstrap.Carousel.getOrCreateInstance(slider, {});
```

FYI, you can pass any attributes to your slider as the second parameter.

Also, the `data-bs-ride` attribute reads once on page load. So, you don't need to set it up in your Ajax call.